# UIHierarchyView in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have converted a project from the attached link to Swift [UIHierarchyView for Objective C – iOS platform](http://www.inovaeg.com/uihierarchyview-objective-c-ios-platform/)

As I don't have a very good knowledge in Swift, I am looking for some help who can review this code and guide me further to make this project stable.

Comment: Hi. This would be off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may want to try on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but please, first also check their guidelines to verify that your question would be on-topic there.

Comment: Thank you Eric. I will check their guidelines

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com.